Changes in the front-end (Vue.js) part of the PatrolHears project (open source code)
I want to use the Patrowl Heares code in the link below. I have made changes in one of its tables in the back section, in fact, I have added a column to one of the tables and changed all the information along with its Docker Compose file. I have also changed its front end. The changes in the slow when I enter the data through the API are visible because the data is stored in the database, but the changes that I apply to the header and Vue.JS are not visible, even though before bringing up and down Docker Compose, the changes are made with NPM has been rebuilt. Please help me to apply the changes in front too.
Changes: Adding a description column to the kb-bulletin table.
Detailed change in the front-end section: adding a column and its header in the corresponding file Vue.js to the kb-bulletin table.
enter link description here
https://github.com/Patrowl/PatrowlHears/tree/master/frontend
change code:
data: () => ({
bulletins: [],
totalbulletins: 0,
loading: true,
limit: 20,
search: '',
options: {},
selected: [],
headers: [
  { text: 'ID', value: 'publicid', width: '150px' },
  { text: 'Vendor1', value: 'vendor' },
  { text: 'Title2', value: 'title' },
  { text: 'Description', value: 'description' },
  { text: 'Severity', value: 'severity' },
  { text: 'Monitored', value: 'monitored', align: 'center' },
  { text: 'Published', value: 'published' }
],


I solve it, json file is cashed in the Browser
